# How to not repeat this jQuery code? and how to had fade in and out to it?

Tags: jquery

How can this code be written better? Without repeating the exact same rows. 
Also, where do I add the fadeIn() and FadeOut() part. I want the background images to fade in and out slowly when hover over the menu items.

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item-1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item-2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="menu-item-3">Item 3</li>
</ul>

jQuery(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    $('li:first-child').hover(function(){
        $body.css('background-image', 'url("img/a.jpg")');
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '');
    });

$('li:nth-child(2)').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background-image', 'url("img/b.jpg")');
}, function() {
    $body.css('background-image', '');
});

$('li:nth-child(3)').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background-image', 'url("img/c.jpg)');
}, function() {
    $body.css('background-image', '');
});
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will be the most elegant way to do so:

```js
$(function(){
  var $body = $('body');
  $('ul.menu li').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background-image', 'url('+ $(this).data('bg-image') +')');
  }, function() {
    $body.css('background-image', '');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item-1" data-bg-image="http://dummyimage.com/500x500/F00/000">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item-2" data-bg-image="http://dummyimage.com/500x500/0F0/000">Item 2</li>
    <li class="menu-item-3" data-bg-image="http://dummyimage.com/500x500/00F/000">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Each of the `li` elements inside the `ul.menu` have it's own image inside the tag definition. I used the `data-*` attribute so it will be easy to get the data using jquery's `data()` function.

---

If you don't have the ability to change the HTML, you can use this code:

```js
$(function(){
  var $body = $('body');
  var items_to_bg = {
    'Item 1': 'http://dummyimage.com/500x500/F00/000',
    'Item 2': 'http://dummyimage.com/500x500/0F0/000',
    'Item 3': 'http://dummyimage.com/500x500/00F/000',
  }
  $('ul.menu li').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background-image', 'url('+ items_to_bg[$(this).text()] +')');
  }, function() {
    $body.css('background-image', '');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item-1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item-2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="menu-item-3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the data-bg-image inside the HTML. The menu comes from wordpress API. @Dekel

Comment: @monss, added an example without the `data-*` attribute

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! My last concern now is, where to add the .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() ?? @Dekel

Comment: You are welcome :) As for the fadeIn/fadeOut - unfortunately it's impossible to fade a background image (not with css and not with jQuery). The solution is to set the background-image to some element and then you can fade that element.